# checking for string in nested list

Tags: python, list, function, nested

I'm trying to write a function in my tic-tac-toe program that checks to see if all three spaces in a line on the grid have been marked as either 'x's or 'o's. lst_1 is a list of all the possible combinations of lines:

```
def conc():
    global lst
    lst_1 = [[lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]],[lst[3],lst[4],lst[5]],[lst[6],lst[7],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]],[lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]],    [lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]],[lst[2],lst[4],lst[6]],    [lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]],[lst[3],lst[4],lst[5]],[lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]],     [lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]],[lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]],    [lst[2],lst[4],lst[6]]]
    triplet = [s for s in lst_1]
     if all('o' == item for item in triplet):
        print('Player 2 wins!')
        reply()
    elif all('x' == item for item in triplet):
        print('Player 1 wins!')
        reply()
    else:
        pass
```

I thought this would stop the game when someone managed to get 3 in a row, but it keeps on going. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have some extra data in `lst_1` that's messing things up.

Comment: And your `all()` calls are missing some key parts as well.

Comment: Your indentation is off, which is critical in Python. Your variable `triplet` seems to be the same as `lst_1`. You do not tell us what `reply()` is or does. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question simply, you're not iterating through `lst_1`. I imagine you think you are by the statement you're using for `triplet`, but that actually just copies `lst_1` to `triplet`.

I assume you're actually trying to make a generator out of `lst_1` and assigning it to `triplet`, but you're accidentally using list comprehension instead and don't fully understand how generators work. Read more about generators [here](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generator-expressions).

While generators are undeniably useful for certain situations, I don't think they'd actually simplify your code here. You're going to need a loop anyway, and you have to check for a `StopIteration` exception to find out when the generator ends.

So, my suggestion is just to use a `for` loop.

```
def conc():
    global lst
    lst_1 = [[lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]],[lst[3],lst[4],lst[5]],[lst[6],lst[7],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]],[lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]],    [lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]],[lst[2],lst[4],lst[6]],    [lst[0],lst[1],lst[2]],[lst[3],lst[4],lst[5]],[lst[0],lst[3],lst[6]],     [lst[1],lst[4],lst[7]],[lst[2],lst[5],lst[8]],[lst[0],lst[4],lst[8]],    [lst[2],lst[4],lst[6]]]
    for triplet in lst_1:
        if all('o' == item for item in triplet):
            print('Player 2 wins!')
            reply()
            break
        elif all('x' == item for item in triplet):
            print('Player 1 wins!')
            reply()
            break
```

Some other nits:
Adding `else: pass` to the end of your `if-elif-else` loop is completely extraneous. It doesn't have to be there.

Also, try to avoid global variables. Read up a bit about scope in Python. It might work for simple programs, but if you rely on them when you get to anything remotely complicated it'll hurt you.

Comment: Thanks @Dodosaur. Why are global functions undesirable?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) answer explains it more eloquently than I can.

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter and it submitted. The basic gist is that it makes code hard to understand, because if a function uses a global variable then there's something outside the scope of the function affecting it.